# stuck on "preparing..." when restoring from deja-dup backup

Tags: encryption, deja-dup

I'm trying to restore my deja-dup backup from a certain date.  However during restore after selecting the date to restore from i get a "restoring... "preparing"..." window that just seems stuck there doing nothing forever (past 1/2 hour).
There was a point when i was prompted for the "encryption password" but i don't remember it, so i just entered one.  I never got any error if the password i entered was not accepted.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you entered the wrong password, but im not sure how dejadupe handles a restore when given the incorrect password. If done properly, it should ask for the correct password until given it, if not then it may assume whatever you entered is the correct password and just keep failing.

Try mounting the drive normally to make sure you have the right password before starting the restore, and let us know how that goes.

Comment: You may also want to file a bug against dejadupe, this is not the expected behavior.